# Odd Headlight Behavior (2002 Dodge Grand Caravan)

Tags: headlight, grand-caravan

When I start my 2002 Dodge Grand Caravan, the left running light works but not the right. When I turn on the lights, the right low beam works, but the left doesn't. When I turn on the high beams, the left works, but the right doesn't. What could cause this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. Was any electrical work (especially on the headlight and/or running light circuits) done recently? If not, was any other electrical work done recently?

Comment: Sounds like it's shorting out.

Comment: No electrical work was done recently

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that you might have burned out filaments in the bulbs. Each headlight has two filaments: one for the high beam and one for the low beam. They can (and do) fail independently.